# Regex[Python] Extract from url path parameters

Tags: regex, url, extract

I have an URLs from the access log. Example:
`/someService/US/getPersonFromAllAccessoriesByDescription/67814/alloy%20nudge%20w`

`/someService/NZ/asdNmasdf423-asd342e/getDealerFromSomethingSomething/FS443GH/front%20parking%20sen`

I cannot make any assumption on the service name or the function name.

I'm trying to find a regex that can **only** match in the first log:

```
67814
alloy%20nudge%20w
```

and in the second:

```
asdNmasdf423-asd342e
FS443GH
front%20parking%20sen
```

with some heuristic, I tried to use `[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]{15,}|[A-Z0-9]{5,}` match only long strings but the function names(*getPersonFromAllAccessoriesByDescription*, *getDealerFromSomethingSomething*) also had been caught.

I was thinking about regex that can do the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]{15,}` but with condition that it must be at least one digit, so this way the function names will be skipped.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heuristics is fine, use

```js
\b(?=[a-zA-Z_%-]*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9_%-]{5,}
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/oLNlsS/1).

**Explanation**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z_%-]*             any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to
                             'Z', '_', '%', '-' (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-9]                    any character of: '0' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [a-zA-Z0-9_%-]{5,}       any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z',
                           '0' to '9', '_', '%', '-' (at least 5
                           times (matching the most amount possible))
```

Comment: Works perfectly, I tried with lookahead but without \b. Thank you for help

Comment: @Alex Please kindly accept the answer by clicking the grey tick on the left.